# LINQ to SQL join when there aren't results

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-sql, linq-group

Given the following database structure
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26791/tables.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26791/tables.png)

I'm trying to write a LINQ query that will return images grouped by tags it's associated with.  So far I've got this:

```
var images = from img in db.Images
    join imgTags in db.ImageTags on img.idImage equals imgTags.idImage
    join t in db.Tags on imgTags.idTag equals t.idTag
    where img.OCRData.Contains(searchText.Text)
    group img by new { t.TagName } into aGroup
    select new
    {
        GroupName = aGroup.Key.TagName,
        Items = from x in aGroup
        select new ImageFragment()
        {
             ImageID = x.idImage,
             ScanDate = x.ScanTime
        }
    };
```

Which works great.  However, I also want to return Images that do not have any tags associated with them in a group of "(Untagged)" or something.  I can't wrap my head around how I would do this without inserting a default tag for every image and that seems like generally not a very good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky, but you can do it in one big query if you have the ability to instantiate new `ImageTag` and `Tag` instances for linq to work with. Essentially, when you're doing an outer join, you have to use the `into` keyword with the `DefaultIfEmpty(...)` method to deal with the "outer join gaps" (e.g., when the right side of the joined key is null in a typical SQL left outer join).

```
var images = from img in db.Images
     join imgTags in db.ImageTags on img.idImage equals imgTags.idImage
     into outerImageRef 
     from outerIR in outerImageRef.DefaultIfEmpty(new ImageTag() { idImage = img.idImage, idTag = -1 })
     join t in db.Tags on imgTags.idTag equals t.idTag
     into outerRefTags 
     from outerRT in outerRefTags.DefaultIfEmpty(new Tag(){ idTag=-1, TagName ="untagged"})
     group img by outerRT.TagName into aGroup
     select new {
         GroupName = aGroup.Key,
         Items = from x in aGroup
             select new ImageFragment() {
                 ImageID = x.idImage,
                 ScanDate = x.ScanTime
             }
     };
```

Hopefully the above compiles since I don't have your exact environment, I built my solution using my own data types and then converted it to your question's description. Basically the key parts are the extra `into` and `DefaultIfEmpty` lines that essentially help add the extra "rows" into the massively joined table that's in memory if you're thinking about it in the traditional sql sense.

However, there's a more readable solution that doesn't require the in memory instantiation of linq entities (you'll have to convert this one yourself to your environment):

```
//this first query will return a collection of anonymous types with TagName and ImageId,
// essentially a relation from joining your ImageTags x-ref table and Tags so that
// each row is the tag and image id (as Robert Harvey mentioned in his comment to your Q)
var tagNamesWithImageIds = from tag in Tags
       join refer in ImageTags on tag.IdTag equals refer.IdTag
       select new {
           TagName = tag.Name,
           ImageId = refer.IdImage
       };
//Now we can get your solution by outer joining the images to the above relation
// and filling in the "outer join gaps" with the anonymous type again of "untagged"
// and then joining that with the Images table one last time to get your grouping and projection.
var images = from img in Images
     join t in tagNamesWithImageIds on img.IdImage equals t.ImageId
     into outerJoin
     from o in outerJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new { TagName = "untagged", ImageId = img.IdImage })
     join img2 in Images on o.ImageId equals img2.IdImage
     group img2 by o.TagName into aGroup
     select new {
         TagName = aGroup.Key,
         Images = aGroup.Select(i => i.Data).ToList() //you'll definitely need to replace this with your code's logic. I just had a much simpler data type in my workspace.
     };
```

Hope that makes sense.
Of course, you can always just set your application to tag everything by default w/ "untagged" or do some much simpler LINQ queries to create a list of image id's that are not present in your ImageTag table, and then union or something.

Comment: I managed to figure it out without seeing this, but this would have been helpful never the less.

Answer (score 1):

If you want image records when there are no corresponding tag records, you need to perform an 
[**outer join**](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx) on the image tags table.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to syntactically do that with this query.

Comment: If you need to simplify the query, join the tag and imagetag tables first, and then outer-join the result with the image table.

Comment: It's a case of adding an 'into' on one of the joins and a .DefaultIfEmpty().

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  I haven't actually checked what kind of SQL this is generating yet, I'm guessing that it's probably not exactly pretty.  I think I'd be better off doing a couple queries and aggregating the stuff myself, but in any case this works:

```
var images = from img in db.Images
                     join imgTags in db.ImageTags on img.idImage equals imgTags.idImage into g
                     from imgTags in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join t in db.Tags on imgTags.idTag equals t.idTag into g1
                     from t in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where img.OCRData.Contains(searchText.Text)
                     group img by t == null ? "(No Tags)" : t.TagName into aGroup
                     select new
                    {
                        GroupName = aGroup.Key,
                        Items = from x in aGroup
                                        select new ImageFragment()
                                        {
                                            ImageID = x.idImage,
                                            ScanDate = x.ScanTime
                                        }
                    };
```